# Замена выражения, содержащего круглые скобки, с помощью replace

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью метода `replace` в JavaScript заменить выражение, содержащее круглые скобки?

У меня есть таблица с продуктами. В последней колонке стоят `checkbox`, при нажатии на которые название и калорийность добавляются/удаляются в невидимый `textarea`.

Я написал небольшой код:

```
var str = document.getElementById("mes1").value;
var AB1 = the_element.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent
        + " - " + ABTotalfunc + " ккал." + "\n";
var n = str.replace(new RegExp(AB1, 'g'), "");
document.getElementById("mes1").value = n;
```

При снятии флажка фраза, к примеру *"Фасоль, зерно"*, удаляется без проблем, а вот фраза *"Фасоль (стручок)"* не удаляется. Я так полагаю, что это из-за круглых скобок. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: т.е., вы в качестве регулярного выражения используете строку, получаемую из какого-то элемента формы? тогда перед использованием этого регулярного выражения внутри него добавляйте обратный слэш перед скобками, как открывающими, так и закрывающими.

Comment: а вообще — это очень плохая практика — получать регулярное выражение «со стороны». на мой взгляд, это следствие архитектурной ошибки.

Comment: И, надеюсь, вы понимаете, что `.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling` - далеко не лучшая идея?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для экранирования специальных знаков (`-`, `/`, `\`, `^`, `$`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `.`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`) используйте

```
RegExp.escape= function( text ) {
     return ( text +'' ).replace( /[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&" );
};
```

А затем

```
var n = str.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape(AB1), 'g'), "");
```

Comment: @ReinRaus: А можете объяснить, почему "эталонной"?

Comment: Эта реализация взята здесь http://stackoverflow.com/a/2593661/1299307 , если распространять функцию экранирования для javaScript, то лучше, чтобы она была такой - с приведением типа к String. Регулярка же ничем не отличается от Вашей, только порядок символов другой.